# Rails: How does session work in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am trying to pass values between actions in a controller. 
When I puts values in the sender action it returns a collection of objects correctly. But when I puts values from the receiver action, it shows different thing.
I met this problem when I tried to use `each` to retrieve every object from collection

**example_controller.rb**

```
def query
  @results = Result.all
  session[:results] = @results
  puts session[:results]
end

def print
  @receiver = session[:results]
  puts @receiver
end
```

> Results:0x007fdc8b96b0a8
>  Results:0x007fdc8b96af68
>   Results:0x007fdc8b96adb0
>  Results:0x007fdc8b96ac70
>
> {"id"=>9, "e_comp"=>"109", "e_num"=>"ccc"}
>  {"id"=>11,
>   "e_comp"=>"111", "e_num"=>"bbb"}
>  {"id"=>12, "e_comp"=>"112",
>   "e_num"=>"ddd"}
>  {"id"=>15, "e_comp"=>"115", "e_num"=>"kkk"}

if I try `@receivers.each {|r| r.e_comp}` , it will show an error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `e_comp' for Hash:0x007fdc8b96b0a8)

What happens inside rails? why session turn to another format?

Comment: can you post more code related to this issue - what is in the each do block?

Comment: @henners66 Thanks to see the updated code

Answer (score 2):

You should not store complex or activerecord objects at session. ActiveRecord objects can change their attributes, and this will probably raise an exception.

Also, is not a good practice to store undefined length arrays in session. Take in account that session's memory size is 4kb only.

For your example, you can store result's ids inside session and then retrieve them querying the database within the print method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@receivers.each {|r| r["e_comp"]}
```

Without the `s` in your print controller method.  That looks like a typo.